# sql: keep only the minimum value if two rows have duplicate id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicate-data

Below is my sample data. Row 3 and 4 have the same st_case (the primary key), but their dist_min are different. I want to keep the row with the minimum dist_min value. And please notice that there could be more than 2 duplicate rows associate with the same st_case. Thank you so much for the help!

[image: data]

Comment: This is a little confusing. You say at the beginning of your issue that st_case is the primary key. Then later you say there are duplicate values for st_case. How can you have duplicate values for your primary key?

Comment: you need to fetch data form this table with minimum dist_min or delete those rows that have not minimum dist_min?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with a `delete` and `join`:

```
delete s
    from sample s left join
         (select st_case, min(dist_min) as mindm
          from sample s
          group by st_case
         ) ss
         on ss.st_case = s.st_case and s.dist_min > ss.mindm;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.st_case = t2.st_case 
WHERE t1.dist_min > t2.dist_min
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM sample 
WHERE dist_min !=(SELECT dist_min FROM (SELECT * FROM sample) sample2 
                  WHERE sample2.st_case = sample.st_case 
                  ORDER BY dist_min 
                  LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: This one will not work in mysql, because mysql does not allow the row you are deleting to use in subquery. You will get error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versio....`

Comment: I edited my answer to correct that. The error was actually "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"

Answer (score 2):

As SAM M suggested, I am not sure how you can have duplicate rows with same primary key.
However in case st_case is not your only key and the table has a composite key
OR had it been a non-key column,
You could write a trigger to control the insertion
Something like:

```
CREATE table CALC_STATUS(id varchar(40), correlatoinToken integer, requirement double)

CREATE TRIGGER keep_min BEFORE INSERT ON CALC_STATUS 
    FOR EACH row 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.correlatoinToken = correlatoinToken AND NEW.requirement <= requirement then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "A row with similar correlation token with lower requirement already exists";
ELSEIF NEW.correlatoinToken = correlatoinToken AND NEW.requirement > requirement
    NEW.requirement = requirement;
END IF;
END;
```

### And if you meant to query:

```
SELECT c1.* FROM CALC_STATUS c1,(SELECT st_case,MIN(dist_min) FROM CALC_STATUS GROUP BY road_id) AS c2 WHERE c1.st_case=c2.st_case
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get to test this so please forgive any syntax errors. [SQL ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) can solve your problem. Essentially you group by one column and then rank by another. Then you can select only those of rank one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
  SELECT *, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY 'st_case' Order by Dist_min DESC) as Rank
  From 'tbl_Name')
WHERE Rank = '1'
```